# Question about RTL (or ROP) chaining order

Tags: rop

I'm confused now about how the order is set up for the ROP chain.

Let's say we'd like to make a chain below

in C:

```
open("myfile", O_RDONLY);
read(3, buf, 100);
```

in payload:

```
p32(OPEN_ADDR)
p32(PPR) # pop pop ret
p32(FILE_ADDR_BUF)
p32(0)

p32(READ_ADDR)
p32(PPPR)
p32(3)
p32(BUF)
p32(1024)

p32(0xdeadbeef)
```

`OPEN_ADDR` is the address to be returned, so we jump to address of `OPEN_ADDR(open())`. When the `open()` function is done, we go to address of `PPR`. This is my intuitive understand but it seems wrong because the `open()` function is already done without any prepared parameters and we're trying to execute `pop pop ret`.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking; can you clarify?

Comment: Hi, I was asking how the order is set up. For example in 64bit, the order is intuitive like below

[Example that calls open and read system call in order]:
p32(PPR)
p32(arg1)
p32(arg2)
p32(OPEN_ADDR)

p32(PPPR)
p32(arg1)
p32(arg2)
p32(arg3)
p32(READ_ADDR)